# Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected " , "

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm getting this syntax error in react native:
"Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected "," "

```
return(
    <View style={ gStyle.main }>
      <Modal visible = { modalWindow }>
        <View style={ gStyle.main }>
          <Ionicons name="close" size={30} color="black" style = {gStyle.iconClose} onPress = {() => setModalWindow(false)}/>
          <Text style = {gStyle.iconTitle}>Добавить статью</Text>
          <Form />
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Ionicons name="add" size={34} color="black" style = {gStyle.iconAdd} onPress = {() => setModalWindow(true)}/>
      <Text style = { [gStyle.title, styles.head]}>Лента</Text>
      <FlatList data = {news} renderItem = {({item}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.item} onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('FullInfo', item )}>
          <Image style = {gStyle.image} source = {{uri: item.img}}/>
          <Text style = {styles.title}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Text style = {styles.anons}>{item.anons}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      )} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I don't understand the error message either, what excactly does it mean when it says "expected ,"?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OUOP.png)

UPDATE

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Image, Modal } from 'react-native';
import { gStyle } from '../styles/style';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Form from './Form';

export default function Main({ navigation }) {

  const [news, setNews] = useState([
    {name: 'Google', anons: 'Something interesting', full: 'Google Fulling page', key: '1', img: 'https://static.zara.net/photos///2020/I/0/1/p/4341/757/800/2/w/1126/4341757800_6_2_1.jpg'},
    {name: 'Yahoo', anons: 'Something didn`t interesting', full: 'Yahoo Fulling page', key: '2', img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/89/1d/83/891d833d89de653904500547b6257218.jpg'},
    {name: 'Yandex', anons: 'Something bake interesting', full: 'Yandex Fulling page', key: '3', img:'http://ideaswood.selbermachendeko.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/8-einladende-coole-Ideen-Holzbearbeitungskuche-Tiny-House-Holzbearbeitungsschreib-…-WoodWorking.jpg'}
  ]);

  const [modalWindow, setModalWindow] = useState(false); 

  const addArticle = (article => {
    setNews((list) => {
      article.key = Math.random().toString();
      return [
        article,
        ...list,
      ]
    });
    setModalWindow(false);
  }

  return(
    <View style={ gStyle.main }>
      <Modal visible = { modalWindow }>
        <View style={ gStyle.main }>
          <Ionicons name="close" size={30} color="black" style = {gStyle.iconClose} onPress = {() => setModalWindow(false)}/>
          <Text style = {gStyle.iconTitle}>Добавить статью</Text>
          <Form />
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Ionicons name="add" size={34} color="black" style = {gStyle.iconAdd} onPress = {() => setModalWindow(true)}/>
      <Text style = { [gStyle.title, styles.head]}>Лента</Text>
      <FlatList data = {news} renderItem = {({item}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.item} onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('FullInfo', item )}>
          <Image style = {gStyle.image} source = {{uri: item.img}}/>
          <Text style = {styles.title}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Text style = {styles.anons}>{item.anons}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      )} />
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  head: {
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  item: {
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: 'mn-bold',
    fontSize: 22,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    color: '#702573',
  },
  anons: {
    fontFamily: 'mn-regular',
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 5,
    color: '#111111',
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that is above this return statement ? ?

Comment: What line does the error appear on?

Comment: Updated with full code

Comment: Error in return line (28:2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the opening parens at `article` argument, or add a closing parens.

```
const addArticle = article => {
  setNews((list) => {
    article.key = Math.random().toString();
    return [article, ...list];
  });
  setModalWindow(false);
}
```

or

```
const addArticle = (article) => {
  setNews((list) => {
    article.key = Math.random().toString();
    return [article, ...list];
  });
  setModalWindow(false);
}
```

## QnA

> I don't understand the error message either, what excactly does it
> mean when it says "expected ,"?

Syntax-wise, I'm assuming it (the linter?) was assuming you were trying to use the [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

> The **comma operator** *(,)* evaluates each of its operands (from left to
> right) and returns the value of the last operand. This lets you create
> a compound expression in which multiple expressions are evaluated,
> with the compound expression's final value being the value of the
> rightmost of its member expressions. This is commonly used to provide
> multiple parameters to a `for` loop.

Comment: Omg my carelessness is terrible, thank you for helping

Comment: is there a way to disable all these nonsense lint errors? is it a real code issue or linter complaining? if linter is complaining i really will like a editor setup to remove all these linters that make react errors more horrible than it already is

Comment: @uberrebu "is there a way to disable all these nonsense lint errors?" Sure, write correct code. I was only guessing that it may've been a linter, that wasn't really the point of the question or answer. It might have been a transpiling error. Either way, yes, it is a real code issue when you use incorrect code syntax. Oftentimes you can configure your IDE to fix minor linter issues, but if the code issue is ***so*** egregious it might not be able to automagically fix it for you.